# Sirius error NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, xtext, eclipse-sirius

So I created my grammar xtext in which I declared a part View, a part Model, and another for controller (MVC), then I generated my model and now I'm modeling using Sirius I created Also my palette, and I was able to drag items, but my problem is when I want to save my diagram, I always have an error " Save Failed
Java.lang.NullPointerException ".
 I don't know why this error and how to solve it, thank you for helping me.[image]

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see is there is a more detailed stack trace. If there is edit your question and add the trace.

Answer (score 0):

It might be (but without the actual stacktrace it's speculation) that your model in memory does not fit the constraints imposed by your grammar. Another way to put it is: your grammar can't seraialize the model in the state it is. Let's imagine you are working with Java, and you have an instance of a JavaClass in memory but no name for it, then the Java grammar won't allow to serialize it as the name in

```
public class Name {

}
```

is mandatory.

If you are not yet aware of [this presentation](https://fr.slideshare.net/cbrun/xtext-sirius?qid=237506d9-4f7f-426a-b7d8-1ade175768e9&v=&b=&from_search=1) you might want to have a look at it as it covers most of the issues you have to handle when mixing Sirius and Xtext.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Sir